# How can I download and set an Image on a ImageView on Android app?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

Hi guys surfing the internet I found some snippet to download and set an Image on a ImageView on Android. But it seems that doesn't works because it don't find the resource... Here is my snippet

```
String user_image_url = "http://www.nuoto.it/foto_news/papera";
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL(user_image_url);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true); 
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is;
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}   


String uri = "@drawable-hdpi/bg_main.png";
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName()); //Here it give me the error (Resource not found)

ImageView imageview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.place_image);
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageview.setImageDrawable(res);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you so much

Logcat for @Hunkeone:

```
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380): Process: com.example.findmyclients, PID: 4380
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:94)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.example.findmyclients.BuildInfoMatrix.Read_Matrix(BuildInfoMatrix.java:172)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.example.findmyclients.WindowFeature.show(WindowFeature.java:51)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.example.findmyclients.MainActivity$7.onInfoWindowClick(MainActivity.java:679)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$9.e(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.f$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ai.a(SourceFile:82)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ae.h(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.g.b(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.bo.aK_(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.bo.a(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.ca.c(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.am.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.i.g.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.i.i.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-13 16:55:57.926: E/AndroidRuntime(4380):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) from square.. Its awesome

Using this you can load images in imageview with single line of code. e.g.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

- It has inbuilt support of **Disk & memory cache(Lrucache)**, which is
  required for faster image retrievals in case of Listview/Grid views.
- It downloads images from server **asynchronously** & set image in
  ImageView on completion of image download.

Comment: super library.. I watch about it

Comment: with Picasso library this is the only row to display an image without manipulation?

Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into((Target) v.findViewById(R.id.place_image));

Comment: @Akhil so many thanks !! I solved with Picasso ^^ Amazing Libraries !!

Comment: Amazing how simple!

Answer (score 1):

The path you are giving to your String uri should just be `@drawable/bg_main` but there are easy ways to assign a image to an ImageView. Instead of doing:

```
String uri = "@drawable-hdpi/bg_main.png";
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName()); 
ImageView imageview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.place_image);
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageview.setImageDrawable(res);
```

You can do

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.place_image);
imageview.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.bg_main);
```

And that's it!

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a bg_main into my application but I have an input stream formatted as bmp...here you are:

Comment: InputStream is;
       is = conn.getInputStream();
       Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

Comment: Then I believe @Hunkeone`s answer is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

After you've received a bitmap image use drawable bitmap to set it to the layout.

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.place_image);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
Drawable drawable= new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

I would also recommend to make default image in case image has not been uploaded (no internet connection etc.

Comment: I will try and I will comment the result :)

Comment: Doesn't work @Hunkeone :/ I post in a edit the logcat

Comment: That means your bitmap is empty
 Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
make smthing like this check:
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.place_image);

    if(bmImg!=null){
     imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
Drawable drawable= new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}else{
imageview.setImageDrawable(R.Layout.yourPicture)
}